# I can't get past a few do-while loops even though their conditions have not been met

Tags: c++, do-while

I'm just doing an exercise where I'm supposed to be finding all even numbers between two certain integers. However, each time I enter any numbers I get held up on one of the first two do-while loops. I assume I'm making a simple error. Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong? 
Thank you!

The input should be x and y, the output should be b. x must be smaller than y, and they both must be between 1-99 (I'll fix that, it should be 0-100.)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x, y, b;

    std::cout << "This program will show all even numbers between a certain range.\n\nEnter two integers >0 and <100. The first integer must be smaller than the second integer.\n ";
    std::cin >> x >> y;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "The first integer must be smaller than the second integer. Please enter two integers.\n ";
        std::cin >> x >> y;

    } while (x > y);

    do
    {
        std::cout << "The first smaller integer must be greater than 0, the second larger integer must be less than 100.\n ";
        std::cin >> x >> y;

    } while (((x < 0 || y > 100 || x > y)));

    b = x;

    if ((b % 2) == 0)
    {
        do
        {
            std::cout << b;
            b++;
        } while (b < y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include input and output in the question

Comment: You may be looking for `while() { }` loops instead of `do { } while ();` loops.

Comment: You are not doing any error handling to make sure `>>` is actually succeeding, or doing anything to recover from input errors if they do occur

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Hey Francois, thanks for the response. This is an exercise for do-while loops so I'm supposed to be using do-while loops instead of while loops.

Comment: not sure why you use do,while. first read start value then stop value, then do a for-loop from start to stop checking each value with %2==0

Comment: You also do nothing to prevent re entering numbers in the second do while loop if the second condition is already met

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'll have to look up how to do error handling and recovering from input errors, because I'm not too sure what those terms mean. Thanks for the response, I'll get right on it

Comment: @Tyler Yeah I wasn't too sure how to go about that. Should I enter the previous conditions in there too? Or should I put them in one big do-while loop? Or is there some other way I can do this?

Comment: @Kyle if `cin >> ...` fails, it sets the `failbit` and/or `badbit` flags on the `cin` stream.  You need to check for that and `clear()` the errors before you can continue reading new input. Also, why are you using 2 separate `do..while` loops? You don't need that. You should combine them into 1 loop. Like Tyler said, once the 1st loop is satisfied, if the second loop is already satisfied you still force the user to enter the numbers again. Don't do that.

Comment: The normal use of a do-while with user input, is to do the input, check if its valid, and break if it is. Then print out the proper error message. Then loop again. So that your initial read in of input happens in the do while loop.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Okay, I'll change it to one big do-while loop and hopefully it'll be able to get past it, maybe it was being thrown off by the two do-while loops? I'm not too sure what the problem is still, but I'll definitely condense it into one loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are telling the user that they entered wrong input and ask them the enter input again **before** you check the condition:

> ```
> do
> {
>     std::cout<<"The first integer must be smaller than the second integer. Please enter two integers.\n";
>     std::cin>>x>>y;
>
> } while (x>y);
> ```

Better would be to use a `while` loop:

```
int x = 0;   // important !! initialize your variables !! always !!
int y = 0;   // important !! initialize your variables !! always !!
while ( x > y) 
{
    std::cout<<"The first integer must be smaller than the second integer. Please enter two integers.\n";
    std::cin>>x>>y;

}
```

This will only ask the user to enter numbers again if the entered numbers do not fulfill the condition.

If it is a requirement to use a `do-while` you need to restructure you code a bit. Something along the line of:

```
// do not read any input from user before this loop
do {
   std::cout << "please enter two numbers x,y such that 0<x<y<100";
   std::cin >> x >> y;
} while ( x > y || x < 0 || y > 100);
```

Note that I did not add any more validation than what you have in your code. Typically you should check if the user entered a number not something else.

Once you got that straight I hope you can also fix the final loop for the computation (Spoiler: You got the `if` and the loop inside out. You only check if `x` is even once.)

Comment: This makes sense, thank you! I'll go try that right now. EDIT: Just tried it, it works thank you!! It's incrementing the number by one every time though, I was hoping the if(b%2==0) would make it all even numbers, I guess that's just making it start on an even number? So I assume I should add another b++ or change it to b+=2?

Comment: You need to put condition within the do-loop if(b % 2 == 0) std::cout << b++;

Comment: Did it helped with your problem?

Comment: @cplusogl you need to put an `@` if you want to ping a user. I have no problem ;)

Comment: Good point cplusogl, I just fixed that in my code. Thank you!

Comment: @idclev463035818 Good to know. I'm assuming you've downvoted my !(x >= 0 && y <=100 && x < y) response, I wonder why :)

Comment: @Kyle btw I answered the question as originally written. You then added something which is basically a second question. I'll not complain, but just mention that this caused some confusion. Some answers only adress the input part, but ignore the computation part. Best is to not alter the question substantially once posted and best to concentrate on a single issue. cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly typical "loop and a half" situation.

That is, you need to prompt the user for input, read the input, then if the input was bad, tell them it was bad, and repeat.

To be honest, most ways of handling situations like this end up at least a little bit clumsy. That said, one possibility that avoids most clumsiness is like this:

```
bool CheckInput(int a, int b) { 
     if (b < a) {
         std::cout << "The first item must be less than the second.\n");
         return false;
     }

     // add range checks here....

     return true;
}

int main() {
    int x, y;

    do { 
        std::cout << "Please enter two integers (in sorted order): ";
        std::cin >> x >> y;
    } while (!CheckInput(x, y));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since it is homework we could just post the code and move on, but I will try to explain what is going on:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x,y;

    std::cout << "This program will show all even numbers between a certain "
    "range.\n\nEnter two integers >0 and <100. The first integer must be smaller "
    "than the second integer.\n";

    do {
        std::cin>>x>>y;
    } while(x >= y || x <= 0 || y >= 100);

    x+=1; // we update the value with 1, to make sure we don't print the start value, and we start with the first even value

    do {
        if(x % 2 == 0) {
            std::cout << x << std::endl;
        }
        x++;
    } while(x < y);

}
```

**What was going wrong in your code?**
The first thing which was going wrong it that you were multiple times asking for input for different conditions. We only need to ask the user 1 time for input, and we will check if that input matches our conditions, if it doesn't we will ask the user again for new input.

Furthermore also this part was wrong:

```
if ((b % 2) == 0)
{
    do
    {
        std::cout << b;
        b++;
    } while (b < y);
}
```

Why?

Well because in this case you only start the do-while loop if the the input number is even. So for example with a input of 40 it would start the do-while loop, but with 41 it wouldn't.

Also in the do-while loop you keep printing all numbers even if they are not even. That is because the if statement is not checked in the do-while loop

Answer (score -1):

Invert the second boolean as `do { } while ( !(x >= 0 && y <=100 && x < y) )`. It's just easier to read and understand. Write your boolean in the form of what you want to achieve and invert it. As for modulo, it has to be put within the do-loop `if(b % 2 == 0) std::cout << b++`

Comment: Okay, I'll try that! Thank you.